# How can I use the DOM to create a label for an <a> tag in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

For example, I want to use the DOM to modify:
`<a href="/helium.html"></a>` to equal `<a href="/helium.html">Helium</a>`

Is there something like the setAttribute() method to do this?

Comment: You would want to use `.innerHTML`/  `.innerText` / `.textContent` as anchor tags have inner content. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: `.innerText` or `.innerHTML` or `.textContent`

Comment: Do not know why you mentioned here Attribute, but also I would recommend you to first check MDN or different sources which are reachable at Google. Simple query 'insert text to DOM element javascript and I got lot of answers. Next time more your own involvement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; set the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) attribute of your element.

For example, if your `<a>` tag looks like this:

```
<a href="/helium.html" id="SOMETHING"></a>
```

then the code to change its label will be:

```
document.getElementById("SOMETHING").innerHTML = "Helium";
```

For better performance, as suggested by Derek朕會功夫, use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Browser_compatibility) instead:

```
document.getElementById("SOMETHING").textContent = "Helium";
```

Comment: *cough* `.textContent` *cough*

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 same diff

Comment: `.innerHTML` is less secure than `.textContent` because it doesn't escape HTML codes.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 The developer is specifying the labels in this case. It's not like we're using ASP or dynamic content or something (probably?)

Comment: I guess it really depends on the use case, but as a general advice `.innerHTML` shouldn't be used unless it's necessary.

Comment: "textContent often has better performance because the text is not parsed as HTML. Moreover, using textContent can prevent XSS attacks." - mdn

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelector` to find an `a` element with specified `href` attribute, in this case - `"/helium.html"`.

```js
var elems = document.querySelector('a[href="/helium.html"]');
    elems.innerHTML = "Helium";
```

```html
<a href="/helium.html"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your difficulty is because there is no ID on that  link, here is a one-liner in JQuery that will change the text of your exact link with Helium (This uses the JQuery *StartWith* Selector on the **href** attribute):

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a[href="/helium.html"]').text("Helium");
        });
</script>
```